# Backbone collection fetching single models

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm new to `Backbone` and trying to figure out how to populate a `Collection` with a `ajax` `request`.

Practically I have a server method that `return`s to me a **single** `model` and I wanto to build a `collection` with all the `model`s that I `request` from `server` ( iterating over `ids` that is an `Array`)

More simply :

```
app.myCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
     initialize: function(ids){ //ids is an array of ID
        var that = this;
        _.each(ids, function(el, i, list){
           that.add(new app.myModel(el))
       } 
     ,urlRoot: 'my-path'
});


app.myModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
       initialize: function(id){
              this.fetch({data: id});
       }
       ,urlRoot: 'my-path'
});
```

This is not working. How Can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Do somethign like this:

```
app.myCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
     initialize: function(ids){ //ids is an array of ID
        var that = this;
        _.each(ids, function(el, i, list){

             that.add(new app.myModel({ id: el }));

        } 
     ,urlRoot: 'my-path'
});


app.myModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
       initialize: function(options){
              this.fetch({data: this.id});

              this.on('sync', this.onSync, this);
       }
       ,urlRoot: 'my-path',

       onSync: function (model) { if (this.collection) this.collection.trigger('add', model); }
});
```

Hope I've helped.

Comment: This is not what I asked dude

Comment: You are doing a `fetch` on your collection and it is returing just one model, right?

Comment: Did you notice that `app.myModel` is extending `Backbone.Collection`: or just a typo?

Comment: typo, sorry, thanks for notice. I tried to explain me better.

Comment: Now I understand your issue.